# SSL connect to mail server. Trusted ssl certificate rejected by mail client

Tags: email, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, exim

I've godaddy's 2048bit certificate for domain and 4 subdomains. 
[www.site.com, mail.site.com, e.t.c.]

Standard Multiple Domain (UCC) SSL Up to 5 Domains - 1 year (annual)

That certificate works fine in Apache, ssl web checker says OK and browser shows green line in address string.

I've added this certificate to mail daemon, it has been accepted by Exim too.

When some client tries to send mail with SSL/TLS connection through mail server, mail program says "Certificate is BAD" though shows correct trusted info.

Client connects to hostname: mail.server.com, server's hostname is: ns1.server.com (not added to certificate), mail server says: 220 ns1.site.com ESMTP Exim 4.73

Mail clients tested: iPAD mail client, Mozilla Thunderbird, Mac mail client

Please help.

UPDATE:

Godaddy's ssl checker says: SSL Chain of Trust is Broken!

Comment: Have you definitely got a certificate for email and not one for use with the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of things to check:

1. Is the hostname that the mail client uses in the TCP connect, listed in the server certificate as the Common Name (CN) of the subject distinguished name?
2. If not, is it listed using type "DNS:" in the Subject Alternative Name X509 v3 certificate extension?
3. If neither of the above, you might be getting "Remote Certificate Name Mismatch" (or similarly named error.)
4. If it is listed, then look for the Issuer of the certificate, and Issuer of the Issuer, etc., all the way to the root certificate of the chain. The root certificate should be installed on the client machine, in the "Trusted Root" certificate store for whatever client you are using (Windows, Mozilla, Java keystore, etc.)
5. If the root certificate *is* installed, then look at the intermediate certificates, if there are any in the chain (between root and server certificates). They have to either be installed locally, or arrive from the server alongside the server certificate -- either the server sends them each time or you've got the intermediate certificates already installed on the client end. Either way, they have got to be in hand to accept the server certificate.

Comment: b.t.w. I've installed correct intermediate certificate. But Godaddy's SSL tester still shows Chain error.

Comment: I found this: http://forums.iis.net/t/1171936.aspx. Did you install the intermediate certificate for Local Machine or Current User? Try installing to Local Machine.

Answer (score 0):

Do the clients which reject the certificate have the appropriate root certificates in their cert store?

Comment: I think, iPAD has and Thunderbird too. "Out of the box"